# Using azure Application Insights SDK with quarkus jar web application?

Tags: java, azure-application-insights, quarkus, azure-monitoring

Is it possible to use azure Application Insights SDK with quarkus web application that runs as jar?

I have tried using it as described here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-get-started?tabs=maven

but it just doesn't work.

It loads the ApplicationInsights.xml file when I start the app with following command:
**mvnw quarkus:dev -Dapplicationinsights.configurationDirectory=../src/main/resources -f pom.xml**

but it does not send any data automatically to the azure app insights. I only see data being sent to the azure when I do it manually via code.

Comment: Follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent) for codeless agent setup.